# Hibernate MySQL select with IN with values or ALL if there is no parameter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

What is correct way to perform hibernate replacement when we have a certain values (a list), we want the result to be limited based on that list. If there is no value then we want to show all, not restricted.

For example the `productList` below could be 1,2,3, then we want to show only COLUMN1 that has value 1,2, or 3.
If the `productList` is an empty list. We want to display all result.

Here is an illustration what I want to do:

```
List<Integer> productList = new ArrayList()<>;
org.hibernate.Session session = new Session();

org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN1 IN (:products)");

query.setParameterList('products', (Collection) productList);
```

Comment: You execute two different queries, or build the query conditionally so there's no IN clause when there's no param...

Comment: I cannot find any other way. Would you consider moving your reply to the answer part. I'll mark it as the acceptable answer.